# How can I do ng-minlength, ng-maxlength validations correctly in angular.js?

Tags: angularjs, validation

In the project, `required`, `max-size-number`, `min-size-number` parts work, but `pattern`, `minlength`, and `maxlength` parts dont work,

How can I correct this?

here is the related code part;

```
<div ng-switch-when="TextBox">
  <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
         <span ng-if="haveHeader" class="input-label">{{header}}</span>
         <input  type="text"  style="width:100%"
                 event="component.events" 
                 validation="component"
                 ng-blur="isInAdminFormPage && checkTextTypeNumberValidation(component.shortName)"
                 name="name{{component.shortName}}" 
                 metadata="component.options" ng-disabled="isFormViewed"  string-to-date="component.options" ng-required="requiredValidation[component.shortName]"
                 ng-model="formData[component.shortName]" string-to-number="component.options" >
    </label>
  <br>

  <div ng-if="componentValidationType[component.shortName] == validationType.VALIDATION">
    <div style="color: red" ng-messages="getFormValidations(form.shortName)['name'+component.shortName].$error" ng-show="isInAdminFormPage && formInf.mainForm.$submitted">
      <div ng-message="required">{{message["required"]}}</div>
      <div ng-message="minlength">{{message["minlength"]}}</div>
      <div ng-message="maxlength">{{message["maxlength"]}}</div>
      <div ng-message="ng-pattern">{{message["ng-pattern"]}}</div>
    </div>
    <div ng-if="isInAdminFormPage" style="color: red" ng-show="showValidationMessageOfTextBox(component.shortName)  && formInf.mainForm.$submitted">
      <div ng-show="!maxNumberValidation[component.shortName].validation">{{message["max-number-size"]}}</div>
      <div ng-show="!minNumberValidation[component.shortName].validation">{{message["min-number-size"]}}</div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

a pic of where these validations are used:
[image]

Comment: Can you also show an example of an input with these validation attributes in it?

Comment: Would that pic help that i just added on the question?

Comment: There is  a textbox there, whatever i write for the validation, it should give me that message, required, min-number-size,max-number-size work, but ng-pattern, ng-minlength, ng-maxlength dont work

Comment: Actually there isn't a textbox element in your code. Maybe I am misunderstanding what you're trying to do, but to apply ng-validations we need a form input element to run them on

Comment: Hello, it was inside text box div, i  editted it on the question

Comment: Please put all the code in your question that creates that screenshot. Like everything in your <form> tag. There is a form element that you want to validate and we need to see the code for it. The code you have shown is only the error message html, not the form element.

Comment: now, i am trying to add Sir

Comment: i added the related part as i know, otherwise this page has more than 300 rows code, and other parts are related to something else, this project was done by someone few years ago, and they want me to correct this part, but i couldnt get what to do..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to replicate your example, but I think this will give you all the information you need to integrate `ng-pattern`, `ng-minlength` and `ng-maxlength`, as well as how to listen for their validators.

```js
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.theInput = '';
  $scope.minlength = 5;
  $scope.maxlength = 10;
  $scope.thePattern = /^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/; ///^[a-zA-Z]\w{3,14}$/;

  $scope.theNumberInput = '';
  $scope.theNumberPattern = /^((?!5)[0-9]){1,3}$/; ///^[a-zA-Z]\w{3,14}$/;


}]);
```

```css
.error {
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #f00;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

input.ng-dirty.ng-invalid {
  background-color: #f65b90;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<div id="mainContainer" ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <ng-form role="form" name="theForm" novalidate>
    <p>
      Enter a word between 5 and 10 characters long - no numbers, no periods
    </p>
    <input type="text" ng-required="true" name="theInput" ng-model="theInput" ng-maxlength="{{maxlength}}" ng-minlength="{{minlength}}" ng-pattern='thePattern' />
    <div class='feedback' ng-if='theForm.$dirty'>
      <div ng-show="!theForm.theInput.$valid" class="error">
        Not valid
      </div>
      <div ng-show="theForm.theInput.$error.pattern" class="error">
        Input pattern is not valid.
      </div>
      <div ng-show="theForm.theInput.$error.minlength" class="error">
        Input length is less than the min length ({{minlength}}) </div>
      <div ng-show="theForm.theInput.$error.maxlength" class="error">
        Input length is greater than the max length ({{maxlength}})
      </div>
    </div>
    <p>
      Enter a number between 1 and 999 with no 5's in it
    </p>
    <input type="number" ng-required="true" name="theNumberInput" ng-model="theNumberInput" ng-pattern='theNumberPattern' />
    <div class='feedback'>
      <div ng-show="theForm.theNumberInput.$error.pattern" class="error">
        Input pattern is not valid.
      </div>

    </div>
  </ng-form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking time to answer. I am going to try to understand your code :)

Comment: AngularJS looks weird but it's actually very straight forward (most of it) once you dig in. Angular 2+ is a whole other thing entirely, as you probably know. Take a udemy class and you'll get up to speed

Comment: Hello Sir, could you please look at my question in your free time? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67980687/how-to-set-date-in-angular-js