# How to set Date in angular.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker, angularjs-validation

I want `maxDate` to be selectable as today at most, (old days should be clickable, but not tomorrow)
the day between i select as `maxDay` and `minDay` should be 365 days at most, it cant be selected more than 365 days, but can be selected less,

```
$scope.dateOptions = {
                    formatYear: "yy",
                    minDate: getMinDate(),
                    maxDate: new Date(),
                    startingDay: 1
                };

                function getMinDate() {
                    var oldDay = new Date();
                    oldDay.setDate(oldDay.getDate() -  365);
                    return oldDay;
                };
```

This is not enough, i only can set days between today and 365 days back,
but i want it to be selectable if i choose `maxDate` as 1/03/2021, then `minDate` should be selectable by 365 days ago, like 1/04/2020 ..

And i want to do a validation like `minDate` cant be later than `maxDate`.

here is the related part of html,

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <label for="sel1">{{ 'LISTLOG_SEARCHSTARTDATE' | translate }}:
                        <!--             <a class="ion-information-circled" tooltip-animation="true" tooltip-placement="top"  -->
                        <!--                uib-tooltip="{{'TOOLTIP_DEVICELOG_SEARCHDATE' | translate}}"></a> -->
                    </label>
                    <p class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="logVariables.startDate"
                            ng-change="formatDateModal()" ng-model-options="{timezone: 'UTC'}" is-open="popup1.opened"
                            datepicker-options="dateOptions" close-text="Close" alt-input-formats="altInputFormats" />
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open1()"><i
                                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
                        </span>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <label for="sel1">{{ 'LISTLOG_SEARCHENDDATE' | translate }}:
                        <!--             <a class="ion-information-circled" tooltip-animation="true" tooltip-placement="top"  -->
                        <!--                uib-tooltip="{{'TOOLTIP_DEVICELOG_SEARCHDATE' | translate}}"></a> -->
                    </label>
                    <p class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="logVariables.endDate"
                            ng-change="formatDateModal()" ng-model-options="{timezone: 'UTC'}" is-open="popup2.opened"
                            datepicker-options="dateOptions" close-text="Close" alt-input-formats="altInputFormats" />
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open2()"><i
                                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
                        </span>
                    </p>
                </div>

            </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass references in your object. I changed the name of the mindate function to make it more explicit

```
function getMinDateFromEndDate(date) { //pass in the relative end date reference
    var oldDay = new Date(date);
    oldDay.setDate(oldDay.getDate() - 365);
    return getUTCDate(oldDay);
};

let endDate = getUTCDate(new Date('2021-01-03')); // set the arbitrary end date
let startDate = getMinDateFromEndDate(endDate)

$scope.logVariables = {
    startDate: startDate,
    endDate: endDate
}

$scope.dateOptions = {
    formatYear: "yyyy",
    minDate: startDate,
    maxDate: endDate,
    startingDay: 1
};
```

Since you're using UTC time, I worked up this snippet showing a way to convert to UTC, how to set up your min and max dates using UTC

```
function getUTCDate(date) {
   var now_utc = Date.UTC(date.getUTCFullYear(), date.getUTCMonth(), date.getUTCDate(), date.getUTCHours(), date.getUTCMinutes(), date.getUTCSeconds());
   return new Date(now_utc);
}
```

```js
angular.module('dateExample', ['ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap'])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    function getUTCDate(date) {
      var now_utc = Date.UTC(date.getUTCFullYear(), date.getUTCMonth(), date.getUTCDate(),
        date.getUTCHours(), date.getUTCMinutes(), date.getUTCSeconds());
      return new Date(now_utc);
    }

    function getMinDateFromEndDate(date) {
      var oldDay = new Date(date);
      oldDay.setDate(oldDay.getDate() - 365);
      return getUTCDate(oldDay);
    };

    $scope.popup1 = {
      opened: false
    };
    $scope.popup2 = {
      opened: false
    };
    $scope.open1 = function() {
      $scope.popup1.opened = true;
    };

    $scope.open2 = function() {
      $scope.popup2.opened = true;
    };

    let endDate = getUTCDate(new Date('2021-01-03'));
    let startDate = getMinDateFromEndDate(endDate)
    $scope.logVariables = {
      startDate: startDate,
      endDate: endDate
    }
    $scope.format = 'dd-MM-yyyy';
    $scope.altInputFormats = ['M!/d!/yyyy'];


    $scope.dateOptions = {
      formatYear: "yyyy",
      minDate: startDate,
      maxDate: endDate,
      startingDay: 1
    };


    $scope.formatDateModal = function() {
      console.log($scope.logVariables)
    }


  }]);
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.js"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div ng-app="dateExample">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
        <label for="sel1">Label 1</label>
        <p class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="logVariables.startDate" ng-change="formatDateModal()" ng-model-options="{timezone: 'UTC'}" is-open="popup1.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" close-text="Close"
            alt-input-formats="altInputFormats" />
          <span class="input-group-btn">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open1()">
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
</span>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
        <label for="sel1">Label 2</label>
        <p class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="logVariables.endDate" ng-change="formatDateModal()" ng-model-options="{timezone: 'UTC'}" is-open="popup2.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" close-text="Close" alt-input-formats="altInputFormats"
          />
          <span class="input-group-btn">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open2()">
 <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
</button>
 </span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```